# How to fix default character problem in Kindle for PC on Wine?

Tags: fonts, wine, characters, kindle

I am running Kindle for PC on Wine, on Fedora Linux. I have bought a programming-related ebook from Amazon, and many space characters after heading numbers and in tables are displaying as what appears to be the default character (a box symbol). This is particularly annoying in tables, where you get lots of default characters, which makes tables hard to read.

My guess is that the necessary character is missing in the font(s) being used. How can I find out which font I need to install? I can reboot into Windows 7 - would that help to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used winetricks to install extra fonts, and just selected "all" - that solved the problem.

Comment: I still have problems with the phonetic characters